# Bash script curl

Tags: bash, shell, curl

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Username: ' uservar
read -p 'Password: ' passvar

cacheVariable1="\"Content-Type:application/json"\"
cacheVariable2="\"Cache-Control:no-cache"\"
parametersVariable="'{\"username\":\"$uservar\",\"password\":\"$passvar\"}'"
echo $parametersVariable
echo $cacheVariable1 $cacheVariable2
websiteVariable="https://example.com/session"

echo $websiteVariable

entireURL="curl -X POST -H "$cacheVariable1" -H "$cacheVariable2" -d "$parametersVariable" "$websiteVariable""

echo "Entire URL IS: $entireURL"

result=`$entireURL`


echo "$result"
```

I want my script like this: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{"username":"abc@abc.com", "password":"Password123"}' "https://example.com/session"

Entire URL IS: curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -d '{"username":"zzzzzz","password":"azzzsass"}' https://cloud.tenable.com/session

But it does not execute in the bash. It gives me this error:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"child \"username\" fails because [\"username\" is required]","validation":{"source":"payload","keys":["username"]}}
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Update

---

I solved it on my own. Everything was correct, except for executing as eval $entireURL. 
Because A command embedded within a parenthesis runs as a sub-shell so my environment variables were missing.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus i checked, but i do not understand where i am going wrong. Can you help?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Summary: don't put commands in variables, just execute them directly. (Capturing their output to variables is ok, though.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried your way also but it did not work. thats why i went like this. It looks like there is some problem in the way i put curl script into bash, but i dont understand what.

Comment: I'd guess there's some problem with nested quotes in the `-d` parameter, but I'd have to see what you tried to be specific. In any case, putting it in a variable doesn't help any, it just adds another level of confusion. I'd post another question with the non-variable version.

Comment: and please drop the [-X POST](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2015/09/11/unnecessary-use-of-curl-x/) ...

Comment: I do not understand why people are giving minus reputation to the question without giving any input. What is wrong in the question ? I put my efforts already in to it and then I asked the question.    Thanks @DanielStenberg for the answer, I edited my code, but still it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Username: ' uservar
read -p 'Password: ' passvar

cacheVariable1="\"Content-Type:application/json"\"
cacheVariable2="\"Cache-Control:no-cache"\"
parametersVariable="'{\"username\":\"$uservar\",\"password\":\"$passvar\"}'"
echo $parametersVariable
echo $cacheVariable1 $cacheVariable2
websiteVariable="https://example.com/session"

echo $websiteVariable

entireURL="curl -X POST -H "$cacheVariable1" -H "$cacheVariable2" -d "$parametersVariable" "$websiteVariable""

echo "Entire URL IS: $entireURL"

result=`$entireURL`

eval $entireURL
```

This works perfect !